# 06 Solstice LE5 DTCs

Tags: pontiac, dtc, solstice, solstice-of-sorrow

My love-to-hate-it relationship with the Solstice continues.

I was having some issues with apparently-random warnings (ABS light, weird DTC, gas cap warning when the gas cap was not loose). The issues temporarily (for a few days) disappeared. Since an autocross last Sunday, I hadn't seen any weird behavior. (However, even though the ABS light was not on at the autocross, the brakes locked up a few times.)

Today, my CEL came back on. I hooked up the scanner:

```
0x7E8: P0171 - System Too Lean (Bank 1) (Pending, Current, History)

0x7E8: P0420 - Catalyst System Efficiency Below Threshold (Bank 1) (Pending, Current)

0x7E8: P0455 - Evaporative Emission System Leak Detected (gross leak/no flow) (Pending, Current, History)

0x7E8: P0507 - Idle Air Control System RPM Higher Than Expected (Current)

0x7E8: P0563 - System Voltage High (Pending, Current)

0x7E8: P0621 - Generator Lamp Terminal Circuit
```

I suspect a bad ECU. Even the alternator warning (P0563, P0621) appear to be harmless, since the battery is definitely getting charged. The car starts right up.

Oh, and I noticed yesterday that the tach doesn't really work for about the first 10 seconds after start. The needle just sort of bobs up and down about 5ish degrees.

Definitely some sort of electrical gremlin. :/ All the grounds I've checked have been fine, but there are a lot of them so it's possible I've missed one.

**Update**

I pulled the alternator yesterday, and saw this. Not sure how I missed this when I pulled it off of the old engine. It's worth noting that the previous motor threw a rod from the #1 cylinder. I think the rod grazed the alternator.

[image]

Looks like there's a short in the coil.

Comment: Nice question!  Good data.

Comment: Could there be a ground that wasn't connected or that was damaged with all the work you've been doing?  Or a pinched harness?

Comment: @JPhi1618 very possible, but I haven't found it. I looked at all the ones that are easily visible and nothing looked out of place or suspicious

Comment: Have you checked the charging voltage? If it's high your battery will overcharge, and you may not notice until the electrolyte boils away. High voltage can also trigger false codes.

Comment: Do you live in an area with a lot of small rodents? Like squirrels, mice, etc.

Comment: @racefever Nope, thankfully! Only the occasional possum or racoon.

Comment: @TMN Nope - I'll hook up the multimeter this evening. I'm guessing I just need to test the voltage  between the alternator's positive terminal and a chassis ground?

Comment: @DavidLively This is one of those times you just find a good mechanic and let them have a go at it. I'm puzzled! :)

Comment: @TMN finally popped the hood. Top of the battery is a little damp. I cleaned it with some baking soda solution, taking the alternator to be rebuilt / tested tomorrow. Thanks for sending me in what appears to be the correct direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh wow, there's definitely something funky going on with the electrical system.

With regards to the `P0563` and `P0621`, have you tried getting a live reading of the voltage from your scan tool or a multimeter when the car is running?

My advice - get a decent automotive electrician on the case. Your run of the mill mechanic isn't the right person for the job

Comment: I was going to do that, then I remembered I am a trained electrical engineer. Which means I know just enough to blow myself up. Definitely over-charging. Thanks!

Comment: How do you mean overcharging? The alternator is pumping out too much voltage or current?

Comment: Voltage. I didn't measure current. Added a  pic of alternator damage to my post.

Comment: "Grazed the alternator" is a bit of an understatement :-)

Comment: It was "grazed" in the same way two freight trains colliding head on "graze" each other.. :)